# Visual Studio code does allow to search extentions from the market place

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio code does allow to search extensions from the market place.
Version installed is 1.35.1

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you getting an error message or what happens if you try to install an extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why installing version 1.35.1 while the latest version is 1.54. Btw, you can easily go to [extensions for vs code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode), search for any extension you want, click on install and it should try to open the link in your vs code.

This should work.